# C reverse number with print and array

Tags: arrays, c, string

A friend of mine programmed this in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int number;
    
    if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1) {
        printf("ERROR: While reading the 'int' value an error occurred!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    if (number == 0){                       //if number is 0 then nothing to do!
        printf("%d", number); 
    }
    else{
        char reverse[11];                   //created a char array of len 11
        
        int ind=0;                          //created int ind for array iteration!
        
        while(number)                       // while loop with the number
        {
            int digit = number % 10;        //calculate the digit that that will be in the first place in the char array
```

I want to know what this line in the code does:

```
            reverse[ind++] = digit + '0';   //add digit to array at ind position
```

I know that it sets the digit in the beforehand created array at the position "ind" and then increment "ind+1" but I don't know what the + '0' does.

```
            number = number / 10;           //cut the number so that we get the new number
        }
        
        reverse[ind]='\0';
        printf("%s\n",reverse);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The `+ '0'` adds the value of the character for zero to the digit. Assuming that the characters for digits are consecutive and in ascending order, this converts the digit (a number from zero to nine) to the character code corresponding to that digit (e.g., number from 48 to 57 in ASCII).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char`'s are also just numbers.
Depending on the character set that's used each number gets assigned to a specific character.

You can take a look at the [ASCII Code Table](https://www.asciitable.com/) to see which numbers correspond to which character.

`0-9` and `A-Z` and `a-z` are in order, which is very useful for mapping numbers.

So 0-9 would be:

| Character | Numeric Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 48 |
| 1 | 49 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 3 | 51 |
| 4 | 52 |
| 5 | 53 |
| 6 | 54 |
| 7 | 55 |
| 8 | 56 |
| 9 | 57 |

So adding a number between 0-9 to `'0'` will result in the equivalent ascii character for that number, e.g:

```c
assert('0' == '0' + 0);
// ...
assert('5' == '0' + 5);
// ...
assert('9' == '0' + 9);
```

This conveniently also works for letters:

```c
assert('A' == 'A' + 0);
assert('J' == 'A' + 9);
assert('Z' == 'A' + 25);
```

The same could also be accomplished by just reversing the input, without parsing the number first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[256];
    if(!fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin))
        return 0;
    for(int i = 0, len = strlen(buf); i < len / 2; i++) {
        char tmp = buf[i];
        buf[i] = buf[len-1-i];
        buf[len-1-i] = tmp;
    }
    puts(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

If your standard library includes `strrev`, it's even shorter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[256];
    if(!fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin))
        return 0;
    strrev(buf);
    puts(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `reverse` is a character array (`char[11]`)
- All standard C functions use ASCII table to represent numbers as
  characters (each character has its own number), for characters `'0'`,
  `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, `'5'`, `'6'`, `'7'`, `'8'`, `'9'` values
  are: 48, 49, 50, 51, 52...
- Hence **if you add 48 + 1 *(`'0' + 1`)***
  you get 49 which **corresponds to `'1'`**, So in general for decimal
  digits: `'0' + n = '<n>'`.
- For hexadecimal digits you can use: `char digit = "0123456789ABCDEF"[n]`